# How to change block generation period？in POA private ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

my genesis.json like that:

```
 "config": {
    "chainId": 333,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  }
```

I want to change my period from 5 to 1.

How???

Answer (score 0):

By simply setting it to 1

```
"clique": {
  "period": 1,
  "epoch": 30000
}
```

For the context: Clique is the name of the PoA consensus algorithm in geth.

Comment: i want change origin blockchain settings, not build a new blockchain.

Comment: No, it's not possible, since it's uint64 in code. However, you can set it to 0, which is called in the code as "instant-chain". I.e., the blocks are generated only when transactions arrive. I never tested myself if this works. I am also not sure if this is only for dev mode.